# Kentico Scheduled task not deleting itself after run

Tags: scheduled-tasks, kentico

We have a custom code creating a scheduled task that needs to be deleted after a successful run.
Similar to newsletter sender tasks.
The task info object has the "TaskDeleteAfterLastRun" property set to true. After a successful run, the task is still in the scheduler.
Is there a process that cleans these tasks? Or, do we have to delete it in the ITask Execute method?
Any ideas?

Here is a snippet of the code.

```
TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo();
TaskInterval taskInterval = new TaskInterval()
{
    Period = "once",
    StartTime = smsMessage.SMSMessageScheduledSent
};

string str = TextHelper.LimitLength(smsMessage.SMSMessageName, 65, "...", false, CutTextEnum.End);

taskInfo.TaskDisplayName = $"Send SMS ({smsMessage.SMSMessageID}) '{str}'";
taskInfo.TaskName = $"SMS_{smsMessage.SMSMessageID}";
taskInfo.TaskAssemblyName = "XXXXX.XXX";
taskInfo.TaskClass = "XXXXX.XXX.XXXXXXXXXX";
taskInfo.TaskSiteID = SiteContext.CurrentSiteID;
taskInfo.TaskEnabled = true;
taskInfo.TaskDeleteAfterLastRun = true;
taskInfo.TaskData = smsMessage.SMSMessageID.ToString();
taskInfo.TaskInterval = SchedulingHelper.EncodeInterval(taskInterval);
taskInfo.TaskType = ScheduledTaskTypeEnum.System;
taskInfo.TaskNextRunTime = SchedulingHelper.GetFirstRunTime(taskInterval, null);
taskInfo.TaskLastResult = string.Empty;

TaskInfoProvider.SetTaskInfo(taskInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I found out that my scheduled ITask was returning a message which seems to be the cause of this issue.

```
public class MyTask : ITask
{
    public string Execute(TaskInfo task)
    {
        int messageId = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(task.TaskData,0);

        if (messageInfo != null && messageInfo.SMSMessageStatus < 2)
        {
            try
            {
                //Do something
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogProvider.LogException("MyTask", "Execute", ex);
                return ex.Message; //Failed
            }
        }
        return null; //Success
    }
}
```